# Updating and time delta in game

Tags: java, updates, timedelta

I am making a Java game and I want my game to run the same on any FPS so I'm using time delta between each update. This is the update method of the Player:

```
public void update(long timeDelta) {

    //speed is the movement speed of a player on X axis
    //timeDelta is expressed in nano seconds so I'm dividing it with 1000000000 to express it in seconds

    if (Input.keyDown(37))
        this.velocityX -= speed * (timeDelta / 1000000000.0);

    if (Input.keyDown(39))
        this.velocityX += speed * (timeDelta / 1000000000.0);

    if(Input.keyPressed(38)) {
        this.velocityY -= 6;
    }

    velocityY += g * (timeDelta/1000000000.0); //applying gravity
    move(velocityX, velocityY); /*this is method which moves a player 
                                    according to velocityX and velocityY, 
                                    and checking the collision
                                */

    this.velocityX = 0.0;
}
```

This is how I calculate the timedelta and call update (this is in Main class):

```
lastUpdateTime = System.nanoTime();
while(Main.running) {

    currentTime = System.nanoTime();
    Update.update(currentTime - lastUpdateTime);

    Input.update();

    Render.render();

    measureFPS();

    lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
}
```

The strange thing is that when I have unlimited FPS (and update number) my player is jumping about 10 blocks. It jumps even higher when the FPS is increasing. If I limit FPS it is jumping 4 blocks. (BLOCK: 32x32)
I have just realized that the problem is this:

```
if(Input.keyPressed(38)) {
    this.velocityY -= 6;
}
```

I add -6 to velocityY which increases player's Y proportionally to the update number and not the time.

But I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: You could measure time with System.nanoTime and then divide by 1e9 to convert it to seconds. Then the time should never be 0. Also what is speed? I would expect speed to be Math.sqrt(velocityX*velocityX + velocityY+velocityY) but then your equations seem to be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, that is useful. With nanoTime I'm always getting real time delta. But, the problem is still here. My game is running different on different FPS-s. Actually, the problem is jumping. I'll add an edit on this.

Comment: Consider a slightly different approach: save the time when you last updated your world, and then only update your world when the difference between current time and last update exceeds 25ms (= 40FPS). Also your velocity function gets easier: `velocityY += g;` because you know that every time one `tick` passed (in this case 25ms)